# How do I provide custom compilation tasks in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, katana, visual-studio-2015

This question is related to ASP.NET 5 (aka vNext) and the new K/KRE.

### Background

I want to provide some C# code generation to ASP.NET5 projects by introducing some simple domain specific language (similar to `.cshtml` or `.xaml`).  Custom MsBuild tasks to create `.g.cs` files are not used in KRE, so I need the new method of doing DSL code-gen.

### Question 1

Are there `KRE`/`Roslyn` APIs to hook into the compilation process in the same way that `Razor` does for `.cshtml`?

### Question 2

During code generation, I would want to access the `Roslyn` workspace and the AST of the files found from the `project.json` configuration. Is this possible with the `k`runtime?

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways of doing this today.

The most practical way to get started is to look at existing parts of ASP.NET 5 that do similar things.

For example:

1. The [Razor repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/) implements the logic for parsing, processing, and compiling cshtml files.
2. The [CompileModules repo](https://github.com/davidfowl/CompileModules/) has other kinds of compiler pre/post-processing logic.

These types of scenarios aren't super trivial, so it's difficult to provide exact guidance. I'm not aware of any blog post or article on this topic as it's a fairly new pattern in ASP.NET.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Your post does point me in the direction to reverse engineer guidlines and concepts at play here. Worth an upvote.

Comment: Communication is still to much between Microsoft team and other Microsoft team to make these packages a fabric for a living ecosystem at this point. Waiting eagerly for more information from the authors. Simple 700 word blogs on a conceptual level would be enough.